# Window tiling in Gnome without Compiz?

Tags: gnome, window, window-manager

I really do like the [Grid](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Grid) plugin in Compiz, but at work I cannot use Compiz on my workstation (Fedora 12). Is there anything similar for plain X or Metacity?

The Grid-plugin gives you a few keyboard shortcuts for tiling active window. For example Ctrl+Alt+Numpad_4 would tile window to half screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can answer this by myself now.

QuickTile does just the same thing as Grid in Compiz.

http://ssokolow.github.com/quicktile/

Although it has some bugs still in it.

Another one is [PyTyle](http://pytyle.com/).

Comment: There is also http://code.google.com/p/pywo/.

Answer (score 2):

You should try a tiling Window manager like [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) or [RatPoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/)

Comment: Also: awesome, ion, wmii, dwm, larswm

Comment: And [bluetile](http://www.bluetile.org/), apparently. :)